# Alternate coloring elements of same classname without any specific hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Given a structure like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="row"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any many many hierarchies like that, I'm unable to find a suitable css selector that will alternate color them.

Can you think of any? Do I have to effectively do something in jquery land?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you can do something like this, and it would work on all .row elements

```
$('.row').css('color', function(i) {
    return i%2 ? 'green' : 'red';
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2sHL4/2/)

Comment: and it'll get automatically updated if new row elements are added?

Comment: It will if you run it again, otherwise it won't!

Comment: ok, I guess I'll put it in when I create my element ... I do control the creation. trying out now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/ and/or https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

```
$('.row:even').addClass('even');
```

Comment: and it'll get automatically updated if new row elements are added?

Comment: No. If you add them to the end you can set their class manually, otherwise remove the `even` class from all rows and execute the code in my answer again.